# Android Frida script able to bypass root detection

Tags: android, flutter, security

I'm using flutter_jailbreak_detection to detect Roots in my flutter application. But attackers are able to bypass using the Frida script. So my question is how can we prevent it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Frida Context

> I'm using flutter_jailbreak_detection to detect Roots in my flutter application. But attackers are able to bypass using the Frida script.

The Frida framework is very powerful and not that hard to use to instrument code during runtime and when an attacker knows the public method name it needs to hook on at runtime it becomes even easier to bypass whatever he wants. For who doesn't know Frida and what is capable of just visit [their website](https://www.frida.re/):

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

The attacker as his life facilitated due to the fact that your detection is done with a tool that exists on the public domain, therefore the attacker can learn how the tool detects a jailbroken device and hook on the method to make it always return `False`.

If you are not aware of how an attacker does it then I invite you to read an article I wrote about bypassing pinning with Frida. While the article doesn't show how to bypass the `flutter_jailbreak_detection` package, the principle of doing it its the same. Learn how to use a Frida script on a bypass attack by reading [How to Bypass Certificate Pinning with Frida on an Android App](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-bypass-certificate-pinning-with-frida-on-an-android-app) to show you how to do it:

> Today I will show how to use the Frida instrumentation framework to hook into the mobile app at runtime and instrument the code in order to perform a successful MitM attack even when the mobile app has implemented certificate pinning.

> Bypassing certificate pinning is not too hard, just a little laborious, and allows an attacker to understand in detail how a mobile app communicates with its API, and then use that same knowledge to automate attacks or build other services around it.

Now, that we are more aware and knowledgeable about Frida, how it works and its potential, we are in better position to understand that defending against its use it isn't an easy task, and we are also in better position to search and choose a solution(s) to defend against it.

### Possible Solutions

> So my question is how can we prevent it?

The best defence its the defence in depth where you employ as many solutions as you can and afford to mitigate the risks and effectively defend against attacks, and this isn't anything new, it's a principle with centuries of use in medieval castles and prisons.

#### Roll your own

You can try to roll you own detection or modify an open source one to use unknown method names, with code obfuscation, thus rendering the current approach of the attacker useless, but this will not take you too far, because the attacker will decompile your app to understand how you are doing it now, and depending on its skills set it will take him minutes, hours or days to bypass it again, even when code obfuscation is being used.

#### RASP - Runtime application self-protection

You can try to use RASP solutions for hardening your runtime, but once they work on the mobile app themselves, they may be bypassed at some point without your API backend beware of it in realtime in order to not fulfil the requests coming from the Mobile App that is being attacked.

[RASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_application_self-protection):

> Runtime application self-protection (RASP) is a security technology that uses runtime instrumentation to detect and block computer attacks by taking advantage of information from inside the running software.
>
> RASP technology is said to improve the security of software by monitoring its inputs, and blocking those that could allow attacks, while protecting the runtime environment from unwanted changes and tampering.

So, I am not saying you shouldn't use one, just be aware of it's limitations, like for the fact that it makes the decisions on the client side, thus outside your control, but when under attack it's making decisions in a device controlled by the attacker, therefore you may only realise that its being attacked when damage was already done, for example when your API was breached due to stolen credentials from your mobile app.

#### Mobile App Attestation

Alternatively you can use a Mobile App Attestation service, like [Google Play Integrity](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity):

> The Play Integrity API helps protect your apps and games from potentially risky and fraudulent interactions, allowing you to respond with appropriate actions to reduce attacks and abuse such as fraud, cheating, and unauthorized access.

The Google Play Integrity service is a good starting point, but you cannot use it on every API call, because you will hit throttling from Google when you go above quotas, and throttling starts by delaying the time they take to respond to each attestation and ends-up with not being able to attest any-more for a period of time or until the mobile app its restarted.

Your last resort its to look for a Mobile App Attestation solution that doesn't throttle how many times your mobile app can attest, and I can point you at one (I work there), but I think I will do a better service to you if I point you to an article written by me that shows how our Mobile App Attestation solution can be used to protect a mobile app from attacks in realtime:

[How to Protect Against Certificate Pinning Bypassing](https://approov.io/blog/how-to-protect-against-certificate-pinning-bypassing)

> Below you will learn how to use a mobile app attestation service to protect your API server from accepting requests that come from a mobile app where certificate pinning has been bypassed. This means that even though the attacker has bypassed the certificate pinning, he will not be able to receive successful responses from the API server. Instead, the server will always return 401 responses, thus protecting your valuable data from getting into the wrong hands.

While the article doesn't use Frida to bypass pinning in the demo attack to the mobile app, you can use the same steps I highlighted in the article [How to Bypass Certificate Pinning with Frida on an Android App](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-bypass-certificate-pinning-with-frida-on-an-android-app) to attack the mobile with Frida and see the mobile app not being able to attest successfully with the cloud service, because it will get invalid tokens, that the API backend will not be able to verify as correctly signed, therefore a signal it shouldn't trust on the request and issue an error response, that effectively prevents the mobile app from working properly, once it doesn't get the expected data to work with.

Evaluate all you options carefully and choose one or more that fits your needs, resources and budget.

### Do You Want To Go The Extra Mile?

In any response to a security question I always like to reference the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.